# Meteor database find() doesn't return documents when app deployed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I've the following HTML:

```
<template name="something">
  {{#each biller}}
    <div>write_something</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

The helper for `#each biller` is as below:

```
billers = new Mongo.Collection("billers");

Template.something.helpers({
  biller: function(param){
    return billers.find({param:param}) ;
  }
});
```

This works correctly when deployed to `localhost`. However, when I deploy to `subdomain.meteor.com` using `meteor deploy`, the div inside `#each biller` is shown empty - no content. I then replaced the `billers.find()` in the helper with `return ['a','b']` (some array), and it worked fine again. So I've narrowed the problem to the fact that `billers.find()` is not working as expected when deployed, maybe its unable connect to the database.  While this is not working, in the browser console I see the following message :
 `WebSocket connection to 'wss://ddp--3592-biller2.meteor.com/sockjs/969/mty9hj18/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
cbd6db56612e463370fc8f0b4c909d896b48d176.js:32 WebSocket connection to 'wss://ddp--5246-biller2.meteor.com/sockjs/849/wr1l0s5w/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.` I don't know if this error message is even related to the problem I'm facing . Any ideas on how to fix this?
**Update:**
I added a line to the helper as mentioned in the comment below: `if(billers.find().count()==0) console.log("zero") else console.log("not zero")`

When run on localhost, it gives "not zero", and when run on subdomain.meteor.com it prints "zero". So I guess, `find()` is working but it fetches zero documents. Why is this so?

Comment: Do you have fixture data present in your app? For more information what I'm asking is do you have information saying if (CollectionName.find().count() === 0 ) {  //insert data  } ?

Comment: @thatgibbyguy Thanks, updated question with that detail.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your code works in localhost, because your input to find should be a String or Object. Here's the [collection.find documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)

I think you meant to write your code like this

```
Template.something.helpers({
  biller: function(param){
    return billers.find({param:param});
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the question. That is how I have written in code. That's not the issue. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "prime" the database. That means that you create what's called a "fixture".

So in your /server directory create a file called "fixtures.js". In it write:

```
if (Billers.find().count() === 0)
    Billers.insert({
       "billerName":"Testing"        
    })
```

Also change

> billers = new Mongo.Collection("billers");

to

> Billers = new Mongo.Collection("billers");

Where your capital letter signifies your miniMongo queries (client side) and your lowercase signifies your mongo queries (server side).